# Connect Kafka to Neo4j

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-kafka-python

I have created a simple python code that generates user_id, receipent_id and amount. I have created a kafka producer and consumer. Python code returns data as a json. Now I am trying connect my data to Neo4j through kafka but I am unable to do it.

https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/quickstart-connect/
I started to check the documents but when I directly copy the docker-compose.yml

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.0.3-enterprise
    hostname: neo4j
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
    - "7474:7474"
    - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: broker:9093
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/connect
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size: 8G
      NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT: yes

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - "9092:9092"
    expose:
    - "9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9093,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093,OUTSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9093

      # workaround if we change to a custom name the schema_registry fails to start
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT

      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema_registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
    hostname: schema_registry
    container_name: schema_registry
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - broker
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema_registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - broker
    - schema_registry
    ports:
    - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
    - ./plugins:/tmp/connect-plugins
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9093'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema_registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema_registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java,/tmp/connect-plugins
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=DEBUG,org.I0Itec.zkclient=DEBUG,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    - broker
    - schema_registry
    - connect
    ports:
    - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9093'
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
```

[Docker containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vIP1.png)

I get an error from schema-registry container which is

```
===> User
uid=1000(appuser) gid=1000(appuser) groups=1000(appuser)
===> Configuring ...
===> Running preflight checks ... 
===> Check if Zookeeper is healthy ...
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,319] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.3--6401e4ad2087061bc6b9f80dec2d69f2e3c8660a, built on 04/08/2021 16:35 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:host.name=schema_registry (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.16.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/disk-usage-agent-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/reload4j-1.2.19.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-server-common-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-java8-compat_2.13-1.0.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-api-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-clients-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.6.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-core-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-raft-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/re2j-1.6.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jose4j-0.7.9.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-metrics-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka_2.13-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/utility-belt-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-annotations-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/minimal-json-0.9.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-jvm-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/gson-2.9.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-metadata-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/common-utils-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-reflect-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-library-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.10.104-linuxkit (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:user.name=appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=51MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=952MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,320] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=60MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,326] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@3c0a50da (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,332] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,341] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 1048575 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,351] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,372] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,375] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,388] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.18.0.5:47172, server: zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,542] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, session id = 0x10000250f890000, negotiated timeout = 40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,587] WARN An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x10000250f890000. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10000250f890000, likely server has closed socket
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,699] INFO Session: 0x10000250f890000 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:38,699] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000250f890000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
Using log4j config /etc/schema-registry/log4j.properties
===> Check if Kafka is healthy ...
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,567] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.6.3--6401e4ad2087061bc6b9f80dec2d69f2e3c8660a, built on 04/08/2021 16:35 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,567] INFO Client environment:host.name=schema_registry (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.version=11.0.16.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Azul Systems, Inc. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/zulu11-ca (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/disk-usage-agent-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/reload4j-1.2.19.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-server-common-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-logging_2.13-3.9.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-java8-compat_2.13-1.0.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/json-simple-1.1.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-api-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-clients-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snappy-java-1.1.8.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-collection-compat_2.13-2.6.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-core-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.14.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-raft-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-module-scala_2.13-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/re2j-1.6.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jose4j-0.7.9.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-metrics-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/logredactor-1.0.10.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka_2.13-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-storage-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/utility-belt-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-annotations-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/minimal-json-0.9.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/lz4-java-1.8.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zookeeper-jute-3.6.3.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/zstd-jni-1.5.2-1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-jvm-1.7.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/paranamer-2.8.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/gson-2.9.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/metrics-core-4.1.12.1.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/kafka-metadata-7.3.0-ccs.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.2.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/common-utils-7.3.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-reflect-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/scala-library-2.13.5.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/share/java/cp-base-new/jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:os.version=5.10.104-linuxkit (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:user.name=appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:user.home=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,568] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/appuser (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,569] INFO Client environment:os.memory.free=50MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,569] INFO Client environment:os.memory.max=952MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,569] INFO Client environment:os.memory.total=60MB (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,574] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@221af3c0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,578] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,587] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 1048575 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,597] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,621] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,623] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,639] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.18.0.5:47176, server: zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,658] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, session id = 0x10000250f890001, negotiated timeout = 40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,678] WARN An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x10000250f890001. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x10000250f890001, likely server has closed socket
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:77)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,785] INFO Session: 0x10000250f890001 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,785] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000250f890001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,785] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=zookeeper:2181 sessionTimeout=40000 watcher=io.confluent.admin.utils.ZookeeperConnectionWatcher@55a1c291 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,786] INFO jute.maxbuffer value is 1048575 Bytes (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,786] INFO zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,787] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,787] INFO SASL config status: Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,788] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /172.18.0.5:47178, server: zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,799] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper/172.18.0.2:2181, session id = 0x10000250f890002, negotiated timeout = 40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,979] INFO Session: 0x10000250f890002 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2022-12-14 12:18:39,979] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000250f890002 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-12-14 12:18:40,122] INFO AdminClientConfig values: 
bootstrap.servers = [broker:9093]
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2022-12-14 12:18:40,312] INFO Kafka version: 7.3.0-ccs (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2022-12-14 12:18:40,312] INFO Kafka commitId: b8341813ae2b0444 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2022-12-14 12:18:40,312] INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1671020320310 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
Using log4j config /etc/schema-registry/log4j.properties
===> Launching ... 
===> Launching schema-registry ... 
[2022-12-14 12:18:41,910] INFO SchemaRegistryConfig values: 
access.control.allow.headers = 
access.control.allow.methods = 
access.control.allow.origin = 
access.control.skip.options = true
authentication.method = NONE
authentication.realm = 
authentication.roles = [*]
authentication.skip.paths = []
avro.compatibility.level = 
compression.enable = true
connector.connection.limit = 0
csrf.prevention.enable = false
csrf.prevention.token.endpoint = /csrf
csrf.prevention.token.expiration.minutes = 30
csrf.prevention.token.max.entries = 10000
debug = false
dos.filter.delay.ms = 100
dos.filter.enabled = false
dos.filter.insert.headers = true
dos.filter.ip.whitelist = []
dos.filter.managed.attr = false
dos.filter.max.idle.tracker.ms = 30000
dos.filter.max.requests.ms = 30000
dos.filter.max.requests.per.connection.per.sec = 25
dos.filter.max.requests.per.sec = 25
dos.filter.max.wait.ms = 50
dos.filter.throttle.ms = 30000
dos.filter.throttled.requests = 5
host.name = schema_registry
http2.enabled = true
idle.timeout.ms = 30000
inter.instance.headers.whitelist = []
inter.instance.protocol = http
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers = []
kafkastore.checkpoint.dir = /tmp
kafkastore.checkpoint.version = 0
kafkastore.connection.url = zookeeper:2181
kafkastore.group.id = 
kafkastore.init.timeout.ms = 60000
kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.service.name = 
kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
kafkastore.sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
kafkastore.security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
kafkastore.ssl.cipher.suites = 
kafkastore.ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
kafkastore.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
kafkastore.ssl.key.password = [hidden]
kafkastore.ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.location = 
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.type = JKS
kafkastore.ssl.protocol = TLS
kafkastore.ssl.provider = 
kafkastore.ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
kafkastore.ssl.truststore.location = 
kafkastore.ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
kafkastore.ssl.truststore.type = JKS
kafkastore.timeout.ms = 500
kafkastore.topic = _schemas
kafkastore.topic.replication.factor = 3
kafkastore.topic.skip.validation = false
kafkastore.update.handlers = []
kafkastore.write.max.retries = 5
leader.eligibility = true
listener.protocol.map = []
listeners = []
master.eligibility = null
metric.reporters = []
metrics.jmx.prefix = kafka.schema.registry
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
metrics.tag.map = []
mode.mutability = true
nosniff.prevention.enable = false
port = 8081
proxy.protocol.enabled = false
reject.options.request = false
request.logger.name = io.confluent.rest-utils.requests
request.queue.capacity = 2147483647
request.queue.capacity.growby = 64
request.queue.capacity.init = 128
resource.extension.class = []
resource.extension.classes = []
resource.static.locations = []
response.http.headers.config = 
response.mediatype.default = application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json
response.mediatype.preferred = [application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json]
rest.servlet.initializor.classes = []
schema.cache.expiry.secs = 300
schema.cache.size = 1000
schema.canonicalize.on.consume = []
schema.compatibility.level = backward
schema.providers = []
schema.registry.group.id = schema-registry
schema.registry.inter.instance.protocol = 
schema.registry.resource.extension.class = []
server.connection.limit = 0
shutdown.graceful.ms = 1000
ssl.cipher.suites = []
ssl.client.auth = false
ssl.client.authentication = NONE
ssl.enabled.protocols = []
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = [hidden]
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = 
ssl.keystore.location = 
ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
ssl.keystore.reload = false
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.keystore.watch.location = 
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = 
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = 
ssl.truststore.location = 
ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
suppress.stack.trace.response = true
thread.pool.max = 200
thread.pool.min = 8
websocket.path.prefix = /ws
websocket.servlet.initializor.classes = []
 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig)
[2022-12-14 12:18:42,007] INFO Logging initialized @879ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)
[2022-12-14 12:18:42,066] INFO Initial capacity 128, increased by 64, maximum capacity 2147483647. (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2022-12-14 12:18:42,172] WARN DEPRECATION warning: `listeners` configuration is not configured. Falling back to the deprecated `port` configuration. (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2022-12-14 12:18:42,175] INFO Adding listener with HTTP/2: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2022-12-14 12:18:42,589] WARN DEPRECATION warning: `listeners` configuration is not configured. Falling back to the deprecated `port` configuration. (io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer)
[2022-12-14 12:18:42,744] ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No supported Kafka endpoints are configured. kafkastore.bootstrap.servers must have at least one endpoint matching kafkastore.security.protocol.
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.endpointsToBootstrapServers(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:666)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig.bootstrapBrokers(SchemaRegistryConfig.java:615)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.kafkaClusterId(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:1566)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:171)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.initSchemaRegistry(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:71)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.configureBaseApplication(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:90)
at io.confluent.rest.Application.configureHandler(Application.java:285)
at io.confluent.rest.ApplicationServer.doStart(ApplicationServer.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:44)
```

Server dies unexpectedly because there is no supported Kafka endpoints are configured.I found similar problems that had been asked like 6 years ago. So that did not help

I have searched confluent docs, I have tried to use different types of versions.

Comment: You may want to edit your post to a [mcve]. Your error has nothing to do with Neo4j or Python

Answer (score 0):

The error is informing you that you need to remove the (deprecated) property `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL` and use `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` instead, and set it to `broker:9093`

You could start with [a working compose file](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/tree/7.3.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community) then add Neo4j to that.

Note: The Schema Registry is not a requirement to use Kafka Connect with or without Neo4j, or any Python library.